# При нажатии на кнопки нужно менять картинки в css (background url)

Tags: javascript, html

Только изучаю js
У меня есть меню из кнопок, при нажатии на первую - в css должен меняться background на другую картинку, при нажатии на вторую кнопку - другая картинка и т.д

я сделал массив c ссылками на каждую картинку, у меня получилось реализовать задуманное только на одной кнопке.

я мог бы сделать сравнение через data атрибуты на кнопке и картинках, и скрывать ненужное, но это работало если бы у меня они были через  в html, а мне нужно чтобы они были заданы через background в css. И здесь я застопорился =(

```
<div class="header__button">
                    <button class="buttons" id="buttonsId" data-action="first"><a href="#">Конференция</a></button>
                    <button class="buttons" id="buttonsId" data-action="two"><a href="#">Выставка</a></button>
                    <button class="buttons" id="buttonsId" data-action="three"><a href="#">Шоу</a></button>
                    <button class="buttons" id="buttonsId" data-action="four"><a href="#">Онлайн</a></button>
                    <button class="buttons" id="buttonsId" data-action="five"><a href="#">Театр</a></button>
                </div>
```

```
header {
    min-height: 678px;
    background: url(../img/slider-img-0.jpg) center center;
}
.header__button {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 974px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.buttons  {
    margin: 0px 5px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border:  none;
    background-color: #3BD9CC;
    border-radius: 55px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.header_text__block {
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

```
const headerBcg = document.getElementById('header')

const images = ["url('assets/img/slider-img-0.jpg')",
                "url('assets/img/slider-img-1.jpg')",
                "url('assets/img/slider-img-2.jpg')",
                "url('assets/img/slider-img-3.jpg')",
                "url('assets/img/slider-img-4.jpg')"
]
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#buttonsId')
Array.from(buttons).map(item => item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    headerBcg.style.background = images[3]
}))
```

Comment: ID должно быть уникальным для HTML элемента, то есть не может быть несколько элементов с одинаковым ID в HTML документе. Используйте класс `buttons` для `const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.buttons')`

Comment: Используйте `index`, как второй параметр для колбека в [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) и подставляйте в `headerBcg.style.background = images[index]`. Документация

Comment: спасибо! а я думал нужно каким то образом сравнивать data атрибут с чем то=)
Все работает